# how to find the number of elements present in an array in C

Tags: arrays, c

suppose I have an array a[10] and it is filled up to 6 places example a[]={10,20,30,40,50,60} now rest 4 places are empty, now how do I print the number of places that are filled in an array-like in the above case it should print 6, given the scenario that I do not know the array beforehand like  I do not have any clue what size it is or the elements that are there inside.

Comment: If that is all the info you have then you can't. You need to either know the number of elements in the array or have a marker value in the array that signifies the end of valid data.

Comment: Consider using a different storage type, for example a linked list. Or separately keep track of array size (as in the number of items that it can hold) and usage (as in the number it actually holds).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`int a[]={10,20,30,40,50,60}` initilizes all 6 elements.

`int b[10]={10,20,30,40,50,60}` initilizes all 10 elements, the last ones to 0.

There is no partial initialization in C.
There is no specified "empty".

> to find the number of elements present in an array in C

```
size_t elemnt_count_a = sizeof a / sizeof a[0];  // 6
size_t elemnt_count_b = sizeof b / sizeof b[0];  // 10
```

---

> I do not know the array beforehand

In C, when an array is *defined*, its size is known.

Comment: Hi when am saying the  size is not known what am implying is that I am taking the the index upto which  the values of the arrays should be entered.                                                              
for example.                                                                                     int a[10]; int n;                   
 printf(" Enter the size of the array");                                                            
 scanf("%d", &n); //n<10.                                                 printf("Enter the array")  ;                   
 for(int i=0; i<n; i++)......

Comment: @AritraRoychowdhury With `int a[10];` the array element count is 10.  With `scanf("%d", &n); //n<10`, code knows the subset used, like 6.  Together these cancel out the " size is not known" as code does know the array size and the amount of it to use: `n`.  " how do I print the number of places that are filled" -->  To print those `n` elements of the array, simply use a loop `for (i=0; i<n; i++) ...`.

Comment: @AritraRoychowdhury If you have `n` first, then if `n` is positive and not too large, declare the array `int a[n];` and _assign_ the array elements.

Answer (score -2):

if the array is a[]={10,20,30,40,50,60}
here is my psedocode -

```
    int size = 0;
    if(i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        if(a[i] != null)
           size++
    }
```

the value of size should print 6

Comment: `a.length` appears to be C++ code (or some other language). This is a C question.